# Can I re-draw a canvas image with its own image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm learning to draw an image with canvas and getting a problem inside this example:

```js
let img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/hrc-siberian-tiger-2-jpg_21253111.jpg';

let a = function () {
    let c1 = document.getElementById('c1'),
        c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

    c1.width = c2.width = 150;
    c1.height = c2.width = 150;

    c1.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);
    c2.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);
};

let b = function () {
    let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
    
    c2.width = 100;
    c2.height = 100;
    
    c2.getContext('2d').drawImage(c2, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};

let c = function () {
    let c1 = document.getElementById('c1'),
        c3 = document.getElementById('c3');
        
    c3.width = 100;
    c3.height = 100;
    
    c3.getContext('2d').drawImage(c1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};

a();
b();
c();
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas id="c2"></canvas>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas id="c3"></canvas>
</div>
```

Inside `b` function. I want to re-draw (resize) its own image with another size (changing width and height from 150 to 100). But it looks like it couldn't.

Then, I've tried to make another function (`c`). In this function, I've used the image of canvas `c1` to re-draw image of canvas `c3`. That's ok.

So, my question is: Cannot canvas use its own image to draw an image for itself? (or maybe I've done something wrong)

Comment: `toDataURL` maybe of some help. Look it up on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Your code flow is valid. Check console for errors. I think you will see there CORS error, because image is on the foreign domain

Comment: @MysterX Sorry, there is no error in theconsole.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** At first I thought that using an `HTMLCanvasElement` in the `drawImage()` call was an incorrect argument type.  That was wrong, it's a valid argument.  The actual issue was that the code was not waiting for the image to load.

---

You need to take a look at how you are getting your initial image data for your first canvas.  I would not expect it to work because you could be drawing the image data from `img` before it is actually loaded.  You need to attach callbacks to `img` to wait for it to finish loading the image and *then* draw that image on a canvas.

Consider my example below that includes an asynchronous way to load an image, how to draw one canvas in another, and how to draw text (just to show differences between canvases).

```js
function loadImage(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", () => {
      resolve(img);
    });
    img.addEventListener("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
    img.src = path;
  });
}


loadImage("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg")
  .then((img) => {
    let c1 = document.getElementById("c1"),
      c2 = document.getElementById("c2"),
      c1Ctx = c1.getContext("2d"),
      c2Ctx = c2.getContext("2d");
    c1Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 150, 150);
    c1Ctx.strokeText("I'm drawing on canvas 1", 25, 25);
    c2Ctx.drawImage(c1, 25, 25, 100, 100);
    c2Ctx.strokeText("I'm drawing on canvas 2", 25, 25);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

---

Another thing that you will likely run into since you want to be able to pull data out of your canvas is CORS issues.  I point this out explicitly because the image that you are trying to draw onto your canvas is from a different domain (`image.freepik.com` in your example).  Whenever you draw image data from another domain onto a canvas, that canvas becomes tainted an you can no longer use canvas' `toBlob()`, `toDataURL()`, or `getImageData()` methods.  See: [MDN: CORS enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

Comment: Oh, I saw where the problem came from. When I wrote this question, the image was still loaded, I don;t know why :)) After drawing an image to canvas, the canvas was still not an image object. So, what I was trying is: drawing an `HTMLElement` instead of an image. Thanks a lot for more explaining.

Comment: @clone See my updated answer.  I also touched on CORS issues that you will likely encounter as well as fixed the image loading function that didn't handle errors.

Comment: @clone, Also, I was wrong about not being able to use `HTMLCanvasElement` as an argument for `drawImage()`, it's a valid argument.